# Call function using Mongodb-CSharp Driver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

Currently, I work on Csharp Driver LinQ for MongoDb, and I have issues to implement a method that like calling a stored function on MongoDb. Actually,I know that MongoDB doesn't have stored procedure mechanism. And I need someone give suggestion or solution to work around for this. The important thing that is somehow data will be done in mongodb without done in memory. For example, I want to return a list with filter condition which implemented by custom method. This method calculates base on field dependencies .

An example is done in memory.

```
var list = collection.AsQueryable<Rule>().ToList();    
var result = list.Where(x => x.Active && CalcMethod(x.Rule)> 5);
```

And custom method here.

```
public static int CalcMethod(Rule rule)
{           
    if(rule.Active)   
        // bypass check null 
        return rule.Weight.Unit * rule.Weight.Value;
    else
       // return something here
}
```

The CalcMethod method like a function in SQL Server. 
Whether we can do this with MongoDb or other, expect that we can inject a method to calculate data and filter without done in memory.
Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: This sort of syntax does not play well with MongoDB. If you want calculated results on fields then look into the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) instead. That handles more of the "field manipulation" things you do with SQL as compared to the general "find" query form.

Comment: This one is good, thanks. I stuck on re-used methods are complex functions which not supported by MongoDB, above is only a basic method. Because the queries are built from UI, it will look like Linq expression query and system permits to do those complex things dynamically. Using aggregation framework is need converter to transform them. If you know something like that please give your advice

Answer (score 0):

Soner,
I think you can use aggregation for that (or MapReduce for complex things). ie:

```
async void Main()
{

  var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
  var db = client.GetDatabase("TestSPLike");
  var col = db.GetCollection<Rule>("rules"); 

  await client.DropDatabaseAsync("TestSPLike"); // recreate if exists
  await InsertSampleData(col); // save some sample data

  var data = await col.Find( new BsonDocument() ).ToListAsync();
  //data.Dump("All - initial");

/*  
  db.rules.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: 
        {
         "Active":true
        }
     }, 
     { $project: 
        { 
         Name: 1, 
         Active: 1, 
         Weight:1, 
         Produce: { $multiply: [ "$Weight.Unit", "$Weight.Value" ] }
        } 
     },
     { $match: 
        {
          Produce: {"$gt":5}
        }
     }
   ]
)
*/ 

var aggregate = col.Aggregate()
  .Match(new BsonDocument{ {"Active", true} })
  .Project( new BsonDocument {
      {"Name", 1}, 
      {"Active", 1}, 
      {"Weight",1}, 
      {"Produce", 
         new BsonDocument{
           { "$multiply", new BsonArray{"$Weight.Unit", "$Weight.Value"} }
        }} 
  } )
  .Match( new BsonDocument { 
       { "Produce", 
          new BsonDocument{ {"$gt",5} } 
          }
          })
  .Project( new BsonDocument {
      {"Name", 1}, 
      {"Active", 1}, 
      {"Weight",1} 
      } );
  var result = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
  //result.Dump();
}

private async Task InsertSampleData(IMongoCollection<Rule> col)
{
 var data = new List<Rule>() {
   new Rule { Name="Rule1", Active = true, Weight = new Weight { Unit=1, Value=10} },
   new Rule { Name="Rule2", Active = false, Weight = new Weight { Unit=2, Value=3} },
   new Rule { Name="Rule3", Active = true, Weight = new Weight { Unit=1, Value=4} },
   new Rule { Name="Rule4", Active = true, Weight = new Weight { Unit=2, Value=2} },
   new Rule { Name="Rule5", Active = false, Weight = new Weight { Unit=1, Value=5} },
   new Rule { Name="Rule6", Active = true, Weight = new Weight { Unit=2, Value=4} },
 };

 await col.InsertManyAsync( data,new InsertManyOptions{ IsOrdered=true});
}

public class Weight
{
  public int Unit { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Rule
{
  public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public Weight Weight { get; set; }
}
```